# tweenMax 'staggerFrom' and 'From' broken with requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

For some reason when I use from or staggerFrom with requestAnimationFrame, the animation jumps and actually acts as if it's doing a "To" tween. When I use the code outside of my requestAnimationFrame, it works fine. Why is this? I need to use within a requestAnimationFrame because I trigger the tween when scroll is at a certain position and I need requestAnimationFrame to determine that position (I was advised that's the correct way to do it instead of attaching to scroll).

Here's my tween:

```
TweenMax.staggerFrom(".box", 1, { x:100, autoAlpha: .5}, .5);
```

I made a quick [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZXLLV) demonstrating this issue.

Comment: woah! you seem to be confused about the idea behind `requestAnimationFrame`. `rAF` triggers mostly at `60` frames a second and will continue to do so until explicitly _cancelled_. Which means, when you reach this condition of `distance < 64`, it will have executed 60 times in a second and will continue to do so because the condition will persist.

It doesn't matter what you are trying to do in that condition, the things to note here are that since `rAF` executes so very frequently, anything you do inside will execute (or try to execute) the same number of times.

Comment: For the same reason mentioned above, `TweenMax` behaves as if it made your animation suddenly jump to the destination values. But as I said earlier, this line got executed quite a few times (and was still going on, put a `console.log('blah');` statement inside the condition and see the number of times it logs in your console panel of your devtools) and `TweenMax` statement got overwritten over and over again.

Comment: that makes sense now. Is there a way to call a function only once within 'requestAnimationFrame'? Like I said, I use 'requestAnimationFrame' to check where the scroll is while user scrolls. Or is there a better way to detect where the scroll is without triggering 'requestAnimationFrame' that I should be using?

Comment: You could set a flag and test if it's true when you hit that scroll point within your rAF, or consider a library like - http://scrollmagic.io/